# Pushing a line segment in parallel - calculating new end points

Tags: geometry

Say you have a line segment in 2d plane. What I want to do is push this line segment in parallel by length of the segment and find out where A and B end up. Here's a picture to make it clearer.

[image: A = (0;2) B = (3;2).]

How do I solve for C and D?

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate the vector $\vec { AB}$ by subtracting the coordinates of $A$ from the coordinates of $B$. Let's say you get $(u,v)$ as the vector components.
2. The vector $(-v,u)$ is $\vec{AB}$ rotated by 90 degrees counterclockwise. (Why? Look up "rotation matrix").
3. Add $(-v,u)$ to $A$ to get $C$. Also add $(-v,u)$ to $B$ to get $D$.